# How does a one-way-function work and what would be a good everyday equivalent/example?

Tags: function, computer-science

I am trying to get a better understanding of its inner workings, like how does it internally function, how is the property of practical irreversibility actually accomplished?

**And what would be a good day-to-day example to promote understanding and explain it to laymen?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually that's not correct, a hash function is not necessarily a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function, still my question isn't answered by linking a Wikipedia article.

Comment: 1. You wanted a day-to-day example, of which cryptographic hashing is certainly one. 2. It's not an answer, it's a comment. 3. This isn't an appropriate question for SO. How does *which* one-way function *"internally function"*, and why don't you start by picking one and reading its implementation?

Comment: @jonrsharpe 1) cryptographic hashing has nothing day-to-day to it. a day-to-day example would be looking up a phone number in a phone book, which until the web emerged with reverse lookup wasn't easily reversed. so I want a modern example 2) your linking's objective was an attempt at an answer, right this doesn't belong in the comments. 3) yes it is, read the rules.

Comment: 1. Millions of people use it every day, whether they're aware of it or not; if you have some other definition, maybe make that clearer when you find an appropriate place to ask it? 2. No, it was a comment, hence a comment. 3. I'm well aware of the rules, thank you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe read the question again, you are showing meta-ignorance of even the subject under discussion. obviously "cryptographic hashing" and "to laymen" collide

Comment: I've read it. It's not appropriate here. Crypto hashing is a one-way function. It's not clear what your problem is, either in this specific case or the more general one. I see no point wasting further time on you.